# Select Div and Pass Data to form processing

Tags: php, jquery, html, select

I have a grid of DIV boxes set up that can be selected, and deselected.

I need to pass the ID of the multiple selected boxes to a form for processing. Here is what I have:

CODE:

```js
$( function() {
  $('div.foo-avail').click( function() {
     $(this).toggleClass("foo-availsel");
  } );
} );
```

```css
div.foo-avail {   
 cursor: pointer;
float: left;   
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    background-color:#cccccc;
    font-size: 8px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
}
div.foo-availsel {   
 cursor: pointer;
float: left;   
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    background-color:#1Ab394;
    font-size: 8px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo-avail" id="1">1</div>
<div class="foo-avail" id="2">2</div>
<div class="foo-avail" id="3">3</div>
<div class="foo-avail" id="4">4</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` to get an array of the `id` values from the selected `div` elements:

```
var selectedIds = $('.foo-availsel').map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();

$('#selectedIds').val(selectedIds.join(','));
```

From there you can provide this variable to an AJAX call, or set it as the value of a hidden field to pass to your server-side code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sadly, PHP is my thing, Java not so much. I have added your code into the page, and the following:

<input type="hidden" name="selectedIds" id="selectedIds" value=""/>

assuming this would do it....variable will not pass.

Comment: You need to set it to the value of the input - I've updated my answer for you. It will pass a comma delimited list of the values to your PHP.